# Why hadoop commands don't work on google cloud shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, cloud

After creating cluster for my project in google DataProc I've tried to type several commands for Hadoop (like `hadoop fs -ls`). Unfortunately it appears cloud shell doesn't see Hadoop at all!

> -bash: hadoop: command not found

Someone on stackoverflow said:

> "It doesn't work in Cloud Shell because it doesn't have Hadoop CLI
> utilities pre-installed."

But I've no idea how to install it or either activate it. Maybe through cluster creation, but had issue with creating it through dataproc API. I've done it through cloud shell instead.

What should I do to use Hadoop commands in cloud shell properly?

Answer (score 0):

apparently hadoop commands works only on VM Instances not on general project directory. So make sure you connect to cluster via Compute Engine -> VM instances -> [your node] in INSTANCES tab via SSH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).